# Iterate through two datasets to create distinct results dataset

Tags: loops, if-statement, sas, nested-loops

In SAS, I have the following two datasets:

Dataset #1: Data on people's meal preferences

```
   ID |  Meal   | Meal_rank
    1   Lobster       1
    1   Cake          2
    1   Hot Dog       3
    1   Salad         4
    1   Fries         5
    2   Burger        1
    2   Hot Dog       2
    2   Pizza         3
    2   Fries         4
    3   Hot Dog       1
    3   Salad         2
    3   Soup          3
    4   Lobster       1
    4   Hot Dog       2
    4   Burger        3
```

Dataset #2: Data on meal availability

```
  Meal   | Units_available
  Hot Dog     2
  Burger      1
  Pizza       2
```

In SAS, I'd like to find a way to derive a result dataset that looks as follows (without changing anything in Dataset #1 or #2):

```
   ID |  Assigned_Meal
    1   Hot Dog
    2   Burger
    3   Hot Dog
    4   Meal cannot be assigned (out of stock/unavailable)
```

The results are driven by a process that iterates through the meals of each person (identified by their 'ID' values) until either:

1. A meal is found where there are enough units available.
2. All meals have been checked against the availability data.

Notably:

1. There are cases where the person lists a meal that isn't available.

The dataset I'm working with is much larger than in this example (thousands of rows).

Here is SAS code for creating the two sample datasets:

```
    proc sql;
       create table work.ppl_meal_pref
           (ID char(4),
            Meal char(20),
            Meal_rank num);

    insert into work.ppl_meal_pref
        values('1','Lobster',1)
        values('1','Cake',2)
        values('1','Hot Dog',3)
        values('1','Salad',4)
        values('1','Fries',5)
        values('2','Burger',1)
        values('2','Hot Dog',2)
        values('2','Pizza',3)
        values('2','Fries',4)
        values('3','Hot Dog',1)
        values('3','Salad',2)
        values('3','Soup',3)
        values('4','Lobster',1)
        values('4','Hot Dog',2)
        values('4','Burger',3)
        ;
    quit;
    run;

    proc sql;
       create table work.lunch_menu
           (FoodName char(14),
            Units_available num);

    insert into work.lunch_menu
        values('Hot Dog',2)
        values('Burger',1)
        values('Pizza',1)
        ;
    quit;
    run;
```

I've tried to implement loops to perform this task, but to no avail (see below).

```
        data work.assign_meals;

    length FoodName $ 14 Units_available 8;
    if (_n_ = 1) then do;
        declare hash lookup(dataset:'work.lunch_menu', duplicate: 'error', ordered: 'ascending', multidata: 'NO');
            lookup.defineKey('FoodName');
            lookup.defineData('Units_available');
            lookup.defineDone();
    end;

    do until (eof_pref);
        set work.ppl_meal_pref END = eof_pref;
        rc = lookup.FIND();
        IF rc ne 0 THEN DO;
            Units_available = 0;
        end;
    output;
    end;
    stop;
    run;
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far. It might not need much to get it working. There are definitely a few ways of doing this.

Comment: @user667489 I've edited post with my current code

Comment: In SAS you seldom need loop statements like `do unil`, nor an ind of file indicator `end =`, because your `data step` automatically itterates over a dataset you `set`. Please learn the basics before starting complex things like hash tables.

Comment: If you do not explicitely write an `output` statement, SAS also defaults to writing one observation out for each observation read through `set` (or each combination of observations read through `merge`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working hash based code using the sample data from ealfons1.  Having different variable names for the key (Meal versus FoodName) mean you have to use extra syntax in the FIND() (or you could rename in the SET or DATASET specifiers)

It will also output an updated stock level dataset.  Tracking the not assigned condition, i.e. what preferences were run out / not stocked for each ID who did not get a meal assignment, would require extra code and output data.

```
data meal_assignments;
  if 0 then set meals_stock; * prep PDV;
  declare hash stock (dataset:'meals_stock');
  stock.defineKey('FoodName');
  stock.defineData('FoodName', 'Units_available');
  stock.defineDone();

  do until (lastrow_flag);
    assigned = 0;
    stocked = 0;
    do until (last.ID);
      set ppl_meal_pref end=lastrow_flag;
      by ID Meal_rank; * error will happen if meal_rank is not monotonic;
      if assigned then continue; * alread assigned;
      if stock.find(key:Meal) ne 0 then continue; * off the menu;
      stocked = 1;
      if Units_available <  1 then continue; * out of stock or missing count;
      Units_available + (-1);
      if stock.replace() = 0 then do; * hash replace worked;
        assigned = 1;
        OUTPUT;
      end;
      else put 'WARNING: Problem with stock hash ' Meal=;
    end;
    if not assigned then do;
      if stocked then Meal = 'Ran out'; else Meal = 'Not stocked';
      OUTPUT;
    end;
  end;

  keep ID Meal;

  stock.output(dataset:'meals_stock_after_assignments');

  stop;
run;

options nocenter;
title "Meals report";
proc print noobs data=meal_assignments; title2 "Assignments";
proc print noobs data=meals_stock_after_assignments; title2 "New stock levels";
proc sql;
  title2 "Usage summary";
  select A.Meal, A.have_count, B.had_count, B.had_count - A.have_count as use_count
  from 
  (select FoodName as Meal, Units_available as have_count from meals_stock_after_assignments) as A
  join 
  (select FoodName as Meal, Units_available as had_count from meals_stock) as B
  on A.Meal = B.Meal
  ;
quit;
```

The 'want' here is queue based:

- first come, first served by preference rank solution.

  - a random queue order over ID could deliver a modicum of perceived 'fairness'

More difficult solutions would be based on global planning, such as:

- serve most people, highest preference rank
- serve most people, lowest cost
- etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: `modify`-ing the meal availability dataset as you go along. This is slightly more concise than the hash approach but might not perform quite as well. On the other hand, it will still work even if your `lunch_menu` dataset is too large to fit conveniently into memory, and you have a record of what meals are left over afterwards. I have renamed variables for consistency between the input datasets:

```
proc sql;
   create table work.ppl_meal_pref
       (ID char(4),
        Food char(20),
        Meal_rank num);

insert into work.ppl_meal_pref
    values('1','Lobster',1)
    values('1','Cake',2)
    values('1','Hot Dog',3)
    values('1','Salad',4)
    values('1','Fries',5)
    values('2','Burger',1)
    values('2','Hot Dog',2)
    values('2','Pizza',3)
    values('2','Fries',4)
    values('3','Hot Dog',1)
    values('3','Salad',2)
    values('3','Soup',3)
    values('4','Lobster',1)
    values('4','Hot Dog',2)
    values('4','Burger',3)
    ;
quit;
run;

proc sql;
   create table work.lunch_menu
       (Food char(20),
        Units_available num);

insert into work.lunch_menu
    values('Hot Dog',2)
    values('Burger',1)
    values('Pizza',1)
    ;
quit;
run;

proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn nodetails;
    modify lunch_menu;
    index create Food /unique;
    run;
quit;

/*Output to assigned_meals and update lunch_menu*/
data assigned_meals(keep = id AssignedFood AssignedFoodRank) lunch_menu;
    length AssignedFood $ 20;
    do until(last.ID);
        set ppl_meal_pref;
        by ID;
        if missing(AssignedFood) then do;
            modify lunch_menu key = Food;
            if _iorc_ then _error_ = 0;
            else if units_available > 0 then do;
                AssignedFood = Food;
                AssignedFoodRank = Meal_Rank;
                units_available + -1;
                replace lunch_menu;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    output assigned_meals;  
run;
```

Comment: I ran the code, and found that the 'meal_rank' values in the resulting dataset (work.assigned_meals) don't match to the rank values in the work.ppl_meal_pref. It looks like it is just taking the max meal_rank for each person instead of reporting the meal_rank that was assigned.

Comment: A minor oversight - fixed.

Comment: The code is working. However, I want to know more about what the inner 'if else if end' is doing. How come there is a modify statement for the lunch_menu dataset after 'missing(AssignedFood)' returns TRUE? What is that modify statement doing?

Comment: The `modify` statement looks up the value of `Food` from `ppl_meal_pref` in the `lunch_menu` dataset, using the index. If it finds a match, `units_available` is updated (within the PDV) and then the `replace` statement writes the change to that row in `lunch_menu`. If there isn't a match, the resulting io error is suppressed and no update takes place.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the replace function of hashtables before and I did not test this code, but to my understanding, this should do the job:

```
/* build a dataset assign_meals with variables ID and Assigned_Meal */
data work.assign_meals (keep=ID Assigned_Meal);

    /* Do that while reading ppl_meal_pref */
    set work.ppl_meal_pref;
    /* Take care can use first.ID to know you start a new ID */
    by ID;
    /* Remember if someone is served (without retain, SAS forgets all values when reading a new observation) */
    retain served;
    if first.ID then served = 0;

    /* but first read lunch_menu into memory */
    length FoodName $ 14 Units_available 8;
    if (_n_ = 1) then do;
        declare hash lookup(dataset:'work.lunch_menu', 
            duplicate: 'error', 
            ordered: 'ascending', 
            multidata: 'NO');

        lookup.defineKey('FoodName');
        lookup.defineData('Units_available');
        lookup.defineDone();
    end;

    if not served then do;
        /* Look up if the desired meal is available */
        rc = lookup.FIND();
        IF rc eq 0 THEN DO;
            if Units_available gt 0 then do;
                /* Serve this customer */
                output;
                served = 1;
                Assigned_Meal= Meal;

                /* Remember the a meal is used */
                Units_available = Units_available - 1;
                lookup.REPLACE();
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

*I currently don't have the time to test it. If it does not work, tell me, so I can do that later.*

Comment: Hey @Dirk-Horsten. I ran the code you provided, and got the following error: "WARNING: The variable Assigned_Meal in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.". The resulting dataset only has the variable ID, and no observations.

Comment: Edited, but still not tested